# Java 7 update 25 doesn't allow classloading with security manager installed?

Tags: java, security, java-native-interface, classloader

We have some native C++ code that launches a JVM and then uses JNI calls to create a `URLClassLoader`. It then uses that class loader to load a class and call a static method on it.

Starting with Java 7 update 25, IF we have a security manager installed (using `-Djava.security.manager` on the command line), that class loader always throws a `ClassNotFoundException`. If we omit the `-Djava.security.manager` on the command line, everything is fine.

I've tried modify the java security policy to grant `java.security.AllPermission` to all code, but that doesn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: You can enable full debugging information in the Java console and perhaps get some log messages shown that can help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: The java console does not appear for me. I don't know how to make it open when launching the JVM from JNI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this information will help you find a solution:

The release notes for 7u25 state that:

> The implementation of
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction,
>   AccessControlContext) and
>   AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction,
>   AccessControlContext) have been modified to improve security.
>
> Specifically, if a security manager is installed, the
>   AccessControlContext is not created by system code and the caller's
>   ProtectionDomain has not been granted the security permission
>   (java.security.SecurityPermission) createAccessControlContext, then
>   the action is performed with no permissions.

See the method "findClass" in URLClassLoader. Note that it searches for a class within a AccessControl.doPrivileged block.

Hope this helps, I am struggling with a similar issue myself.

Regards.